# mongodump is abruptly getting killed inside a container of mongo:latest image

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-container, mongodump

I am running a container with image mongo:latest. Starting the container:

```sh
sudo docker run -it -v  /tmp/adhock-container/mongo_latest:/tmp/ mongo:latest /bin/bash
```

I want to take the backup of Mongo database so I run the following:

```sh
# mongodump -vvvv --host MY_HOSTNAME --port 27017 --username MY_USERNAME --password MY_PASSWORD --gzip --archive=ARCHIVE_PATH
```

In the console log I am getting only the following output:

```sh
2020-04-06T08:00:08.007+0000    done dumping ******** (1104 documents)
2020-04-06T08:00:08.007+0000    writing ************ to archive 'standalone.gzip'
2020-04-06T08:00:08.007+0000    MuxIn open ************_log
Killed
#
```

Server memory stats

```sh
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            459         328           6           0         124         123
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Not sure why my mongodump process is getting killed. I think it may be because of memory issues but I am not sure how to fine tune those customizations.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with consulting the MongoDB server log. See "Container shell access and viewing MongoDB logs" [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/) if this is the image you are using.

To determine whether your container is running out of memory, get a shell on it and run `top` while dumping.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg, could you please give example of this? I am unable to follow you suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, it happened when I was executing `mongodump` on the database host system. However, I did small workaround, for me the the infra looked like:
`Source Mongo <---> My PC <---> Dest Mongo (K8S)`

I did run `mongorestore` on my PC, in container, connected to remote machine and dumped to another remote instance. This was slower but didn't kill the process.

1. Run mongorestore on your PC and ensure you have access to remote DB or do a port-forwarding thingy.
   `$ docker run --network host --entrypoint bash -it  mongo:4.2`
2. Dump the archive
   `$ mongodump --archive=test.archive --db db --username username --host <address>`
3. Restore the archive from inside the container
   `$ mongorestore --archive=test.archive --db db --username username --host <address>`

This is the only way I managed to not crash the mongodump. If someone runs into this issue, I would consider having mongo container on your OS/some different machine, do a dump from this point and then restore as mentioned.